# Launch a program into a specific xid, (x window id)

Tags: x11, window

[Tabbed](http://tools.suckless.org/tabbed/) gives me a xid to launch a program in, but how?

Comment: What do you mean by “xid” or “x window id” here? If you mean the X11 window id of the program's main window (or any other window), that cannot be chosen by the application or by the window manager, it's chosen by the X server.

Comment: for example in tabbed, when you open it it spits out a number for example 0x320005. What do I do with this to put an application in it?

Comment: I don't know what tabbed is, or how you make it spit out a number. A number like 0x320005 is in the right ballpark for an X11 window id. As I wrote, you don't “put an application in” an X11 window id. The X server assigns it to the application. If you explain what tabbed is, I might be able to confirm what that id is.

Comment: @Gilles its a application by Suckless Tools, though they have zero documentation in their man. People use it sort of like tmux

Comment: I see, tabbed is designed to run programs that output in an existing X window, as opposed to creating their own. So, what is your question? Are you trying to use tabbed with a program that isn't specifically designed for that (the short answer is that you can't — there may be a long answer that involves Xnest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the one line summary for `tabbed`, it seems that `tabbed` provides an `xid` of a window into which an xembed-aware application can be placed.

Reading the man page for `xterm` I can see the `-info windowID` option, which is explained as « *Given  an  X window identifier (an integer, which can be hexadecimal, octal or decimal according to whether it begins with "0x", "0" or neither), xterm  will reparent  its  top-level  shell  widget to that window.  This is used to embed xterm within other applications.* »

I would suggest, therefore, that if `tabbed` provides a number such as `0x320005` and you were to run `xterm -into 0x320005`, you'd find the `xterm` running inside the window provided by `tabbed`.

The bottom line, though, is that unless your target application supports XEmbed you're not likely to have a lot of use for `tabbed`.

---

*Disclaimer: I don't have `tabbed` installed.*